# Add 'auto_now' DateTimeField to existing Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible to add to existing model `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` DateTime fields?

```
class ExistingModel(models.Model):
    # ... model stuff
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

We can't add this fields without `default`, but adding the `default` value gives an error:

`./manage.py makemigrations`

returns:

```
(fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make that happen in 2 separate migrations.

First, add a `default=<some datetime>` to both of your new datetime fields and create that migration.

Then remove the `default` and add `auto_now` parameters and create the 2nd migration.

**Update -**

It's possible to have both of these combined into a single migration (preserving the order) by generating the 2 migrations and simply cut-paste the 2nd migrations' content into the first (and then delete the 2nd migration file).

example migration file `00XY_existing_model_add_timestamps` -

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.utils import timezone


def update_datetimes(app, schema_editor):
    print()  # new line
    ExistingModel = app.get_model("my_app", "ExistingModel")
    for instance in ExistingModel.objects.all():
        instance.created_at = # calculate & set something based on the instance attributes
        instance.updated_at = # calculate & set something based on the instance attributes
    print("\tUpdated created_at & updated_at for all rows in ExistingModel")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("my_app", "00XX_previous_migration")]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="ExistingModel",
            name="created_at",  # name of your new field
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now),  # replace timezone.now with any datetime value you want 
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="ExistingModel",
            name="updated_at",  # name of your new field
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now),  # replace timezone.now with any datetime value you want 
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        # uncomment the below migration operation if you want to dynamically set old datetimes
        # migrations.RunPython(
        #     update_datetimes, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop
        # ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="ExistingModel",
            name="created_at",
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="ExistingModel",
            name="updated_at",
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: I think combining both of the actions into a single migration could create problems if you have multiple service instances running and do a staged rollout (blue/green deployment). Assuming you run the migration first, some instances won't be updated (yet) to set the field correctly, requests to those instances will either fail, or put the DB into an inconsistent state.

Comment: Yes, surely. In that case it needs to be 2-stage release anyway, so 2 separate migrations.